# Ffmpeg on Mac OSx: cannot see Firewire cameras

Tags: mac, ffmpeg, operating-systems, firewire

I am trying to use ffmpeg on Mac Os x (High Sierra and Mojave: makes no difference) with a camcorder attached to a Firewire port (more precisely, I have a MacMini and the Firewire is attached to a Firewire-to-Lightning connector). I could find no way to see the camera as an input device with ffmpeg.

I saw that a special build can be compiled under Linux with support for Firewire, but not for Os X (which anyhow should have FireWire support natively).

Does anybody has any hint as how to solve this problem?

Comment: Whether the _OS_ has native FireWire support and whether the _program_ has native FireWire support have nothing to do with each other. Linux has a native FireWire stack as well – but programs still need to know how to use it.

Comment: Thank you grawity for the  clarification. But my question is if there is a way to see firewire cameras under Os X from ffmpeg. Is anybody aware of any solution?

Answer (score 0):

when i attempted something similar years ago like 2008 i simply used quicktime to acquire from a camera any camera and then used Ffmpeg to convert/ transcode it to the format desired. i used everything from the old isight firewire camera to super high end panasonic video cameras. my rule of thumb was use mac native tools to get stuff in your system and third party tools to get it out.